# Egoroff's Theorem-related

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable for $n \geq 1$.
Suppose $f(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow } f_n(x)$ exists almost everywhere.

Show that if $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)< \epsilon$ so that the convergence is uniform on $[-n,n ] - E$ for every $n \geq 1$.

This is sort of like Egoroff's Theorem. But $m(\mathbb{R})=\infty$ in this case. So we can't use Egoroff's theorem.

I tried to follow the prove of Egoroff's Theorem. But not sure how to proceed, because the measure of $\mathbb{R}$ is not finite.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just take $E=[-n,n]-F$, then $F=[-n,n] -E$ , and you have a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)< \epsilon$ so that the convergence is uniform on $[-n,n ] - E$ for every $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Oh wait, but we can't apply Egoroff's theorem here, because $m(\mathbb{R})= \infty.$

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us clarify the notation in the question.

The question is:

> Let $f_i: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable for $i \geq 1$.
> Suppose $f(x)=\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f_i(x)$ exists almost everywhere.
>
> Show that, for every $n \geq 1$, if $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)< \epsilon$ so that the convergence is uniform on $[-n,n ] - E$.

Given any $n \geq 1$, we have that $m([-n,n]) <+\infty$. So we can apply Egoroff's Theorem to $f_i$ and $f$ restricted to $[-n,n]$.

By apply Egoroff's Theorem to to $f_i$ and $f$ restricted to $[-n,n]$, we have that:
if $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a measurable set $F \subset [-n,n]$ with $m([-n,n]-F)< \epsilon$ and the convergence is uniform on $F$.

Now, take $E= [-n,n]-F$. Then, since $F \subset [-n,n]$, we have $F= [-n,n]-E$.

So, we have that: if $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a measurable set $E \subset [-n,n] \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)< \epsilon$ so that the convergence is uniform on $[-n,n ] - E$.

So, we have proved that: for every $n \geq 1$, if $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)< \epsilon$ so that the convergence is uniform on $[-n,n ] - E$.